# Android - OnDestroy remove interstitial ad?

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

This question is asked more, but there are different solutions given and I honestly don't know what the best practice is here.

I've got an interstitial ad like this (Google Admob SDK):

```
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
```

However the ad is delayed a bit and if a user quickly navigates (within a second or two), then the ads shows at a different screen than I would like, or even worse when the application is already in the background.

[How to pause interstitial Ads when Android application goes to background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990793/how-to-pause-interstitial-ads-when-android-application-goes-to-background) shows a function that doesn't exist (anymore). 
[When dismiss interstitial DFP ad on Android, the app crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709775/when-dismiss-interstitial-dfp-ad-on-android-the-appli-is-closed?rq=1) uses a different ad apparently than I do... is this better to use?  
[programmatically close an Interstitial ad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145885/programmatically-close-an-interstitial-ad) simply says it's impossible to cancel it.

What i preferably would like it to just cancel the ad in the `onDestroy()` function and pause (or destroy aswell) the ad in the `onPause()` function.

Is this possible to do? Any workaround or what not is also fine, but I of course prefer a clean solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really have shown some code, but from your symptoms I suspect you are showing your Interstitial from the #onAdReceived method of an AdListener. **DO NOT DO THIS**

You should be showing your Interstitial at a natural break point in your app instead. Otherwise you will get the behaviour described as well as provide an extremely poor user experience.

Comment: I do load it in the onAdLoaded function triggered with the AdListener. Is this poor practice? Please ebolarate. The point in the app is somewhat a break point: they can choose a level..

Comment: Yes is it poor practice. At the natural break point, **if** you have an add call #displayInterstitial. Don't call it as soon as an ad is provided by the ad network.

Answer (score 3):

As William pointed out, you should not show it in onAdReceived. What I do is set a boolean flag in onAdReceived, then I have a background thread do an empty while loop (with a timer) and check the boolean before calling show().

I still call isLoaded(), but at that point I do know it's loaded. The reason why I don't just use isLoaded() by itself is because it has to run on the UI thread and I don't want to block the UI while I wait for the ad to load.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to invalidate showing ads when the activity finished:

```
@Override
public void onAdClosed() {
    mInterstitialAd = null;
}

@Override
public void onAdLoaded() {
    if (mInterstitialAd != null)
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    mInterstitialAd = null;
}

@Override
public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    mInterstitialAd = null;
}

onDestroy / onStop() {
    mIntertitial = null;
}
```